# How to deal with unfriendly (Non-std) URLs - Scraping in Python

Tags: url, web-scraping, token

When I have non-uniform URLs for 2 different stock tickers like this:

> http://www.exampledomain/t/23353/msft
>   http://www.exampledomain/t/40090/aapl

They not only differ in the ticker-name at the ending of the URL, but also with a proprietary ticker no. in the middle of the URL that I cannot know beforehand, prior to scraping news from this site.

How could I successfully scrape from this site. I see only one solution ie. to use selenium to search for the ticker and let it show the news, that I am interested in to proceed with harvesting them.

Is there a simple Python way to approach an unfriendly URL like this?

Comment: Does "msft" and "aapl" at the end of the URL actually matter? If you take it off, do you get the to same page?

Comment: Actually it doesnt, URL works without the ticker code, but the alpha code is the content of my list that I need to iterate through. So the alpha numeric code is the one I need to use.

Comment: one assumes that they have `exampledomain` has some search functionality you can use to get the ID for a given ticker. you could then build up a map in your program that links `msft` to `23353` and so on. I'd worry that *most* sites that publish this sort of information online would be against people scraping it, though -- so they probably put some barriers in place to try and stop you.